# get column name from variable in with function

Tags: r

I can use `with` function following way:

```
with(mtcars, sum(mpg))
# [1] 642.9
```

Is it possible to load column name from variable? I've tried following with no luck:

```
column <- "mpg"
with(mtcars, sum(column))
# Error in sum(column) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
with(mtcars, sum(eval(column)))
# Error in sum(eval(column)) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Comment: How about just `sum(mtcars[column])`? Or more generally `mtcars[[column]]` for single column and `mtcars[, column]` for columns vector

Comment: I know about this approach but it is not what I want. Thanks anyway. PS: may I ask why I've been down voted?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't downvoted. I"d guess maybe because someone thought it's a XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of options.  Either we use `eval` with `as.name/as.symbol`

```
with(mtcars, sum(eval(as.name(column))))
#[1] 642.9
```

Or we can use `get`

```
with(mtcars, sum(get(column)))
#[1] 642.9
```